# How can I make my theme look like this?

Tags: jquery, css, view, themes

How can I make my theme look like this:

http://neptunethemes.com/demo/neptune/

is it done with views , css , css 3 or jquery?

I'm using responsive bartik or lexi

Comment: tried anything so far ?

Comment: Check this if you want to make the layout like neptune http://masonry.desandro.com/ .. try something

Comment: thanks.can you please tell me how to use this?I know to use it with html pages,but with drupal theme and php I don't even know how to start.

Comment: ok.I got it. drupal Masonry modules at https://drupal.org/project/masonry

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own using [Jquery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com/). It's not that hard to use. There are lots of good tutorials around.